# How to apply style property angular auto complete

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app I have autocomplete

**template.html**

```
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async);index as i" [value] ="option">
           {{option.name}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

The drop down shown  in the picture, I want the color to be in white color and text color must be black, how to do this?

I tried applying styles for mat-autocomplete attr to bg-color=white and color=black. But this has not worked out. Please help me :)

I also want to display complete word for ex: 1069842(CADMinexxxxx) should be displayed and not 1069842(CAD...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in style.css

```
.mat-option{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 3):

Override the styles,

```
::ng-deep mat-option {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ininiv , You answer is looks more correct but it doesn't apply the style, however what Prince Kumar Dwivedi commented works . I have this style specified in component.css. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ::ng-deep is generally used to override the styles of 3rd party library components where you get some issues on using general way of overriding styles. 

::ng-deep forces the styles to it's child components.

Answer (score 0):

> In the document for [MatAutocomplete ][1] there is a property for exactly what you need:

`@Input() panelWidth: string | number`

```
 Specify the width of the autocomplete panel. Can be any CSS sizing value, otherwise it will match the width of its host.

By using this property you are not in the risk of meddling with anything else inherited from cdk-overlay-pane.

For further customization you might find this property useful as well: 

@Input('class') classList: string

Takes classes set on the host mat-autocomplete element and applies them to the panel inside the overlay container to allow for easy styling.
```

Comment: Hi I am new to Angular, I have added  @Input() panelWidth: string | number to component.ts then what I have to do?